# SQL group by and erase rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table looks like this

```
company_name | feature_name | feature_value
 abc         |   income     |  315
 abc         |   cash       |  213
 abc         |   val        |  9
 goo         |   income     |  123
 goo         |   cash       |  487
 goo         |   val        |  990 
 sdf         |   income     |  null value
 sdf         |   cash       |  null value
 sdf         |    val       |  null value
```

Here is the script I used

```
select company_name, 
         max(case when feature_name='income' then feature_value end) as income_value,
         max(case when feature_name='val' then feature_value end) as val_value
   from a_table
   group by company_name
```

I got

```
company_name | income_value | val_value
 abc         |   315        |  9
 goo         |   123        |  990
 sdf         |   null       |  null
```

But what I want is only to get rows where not all values that I'm interested in (income_value, val_value) are null. Like

```
company_name | income_value | val_value
 abc         |   315        |  9
 goo         |   123        |  990
```

Except for doing select twice to get rid of the value null rows, is there any faster way to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: Post the SQL script you're working with? What does your `where` clause look like?

Comment: @jenny “I want is only to get rows where not all values ... are null” - do you mean null values anywhere in a row, or only when *all* the values are null?

Comment: @dijksterhuis I mean where both income_value and val_value are null. By the way, the company_name is not a primary key here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause with the condition you want:

```
SELECT
  company_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'income' THEN feature_value END) AS income,
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'val' THEN feature_value END) AS val
FROM tablename
GROUP BY company_name
HAVING 
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'income' THEN feature_value END) IS NOT NULL
  OR
  MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'val' THEN feature_value END) IS NOT NULL
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/83msQFGKNPwWk93KzDNpUT/1).
Results:

```
| company_name | income | val |
| ------------ | ------ | --- |
| abc          | 315    | 9   |
| goo          | 123    | 990 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the nulls in the HAVING CLAUSE like

```
    SELECT
      company_name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'income' THEN feature_value end) as income,
      MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'val' THEN feature_value end) as val
    FROM
      table1
    GROUP BY company_name
    HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'income' THEN feature_value end) is not null 
    AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN feature_name = 'val' THEN feature_value end) is not null;
```

Comment: Great job! I see that you changed the name of the table and also you wrote `is not null` in lowercase.

Comment: But you changed OR to AND so your answer is wrong. I hope @Jenny did not upvote this.

Comment: @forpas don't get it wrong, it is a co-incident; I was also copied the code from the link in the question so do you i guess, while i was checking the code you have replied and my already opened session didn't show it up until i posted; BTW no one is harmed purpose served :)

Comment: Fine, if this is the case then since your answer is wrong then delete it.

Comment: I think the question was "But what I want is only to get rows where not all values that I'm interested in (income_value, val_value) are null." so it means if  both values are null it needs to be removed. So AND is the correct one?

Comment: No AND is wrong because if only one of the columns is null the row should be returned, but AND will remove it. Do you get it?

Comment: Ok but it says this  "all values that I'm interested in (income_value, val_value) are null" I out!! Have a Great Day!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat case filters with HAVING, just add the "is not null: in a WHERE clause.

```
with  a_table(company_name, feature_name, feature_value) as
 (  values ('abc', 'income', 315)
        , ('abc', 'cash',   213)
        , ('abc', 'val',    9)
        , ('goo', 'income', 123)
        , ('goo', 'cash',   487)
        , ('goo', 'val',    990)
        , ('sdf', 'income', null)
        , ('sdf', 'cash',   null)
        , ('sdf', 'val',    null)
 )
select company_name 
     , max(case when feature_name='income' then feature_value end) as income_value
     , max(case when feature_name='val' then feature_value end) as val_value
  from a_table
 where feature_value is not null
 group by company_name;
```

It also eliminates the need to process the through the case predicates.